# Android debugger jumping fragment methods

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, okhttp

I am having an issue with a fragment that I am building. Basically, right now all I want to do is check to see where and how to make http requests calls inside the fragment.

Thus far when I run the code without the debugger everything works and the logs do function. But when I try to go over everything step by step I get nothing. And the debugger jumps from the portion of the code that runs on the `call.enqueu` method to the end of the method declaration. The code that I am using is the following, please note that this proceadure works perfect when being run from an activity and not from a fragment which makes me believe that the issue is inside my implementation of the fragment.

The method for the async requestÑ:

```
public void testAsyncCreate() {

OkHttpClient client  = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(CREATE_MEDIA_TYPE, "data={\"process\":\"12222\", \"phone\":\"1111111\"}");

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(ALLWAYS_API)
        .post(body)
        .build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);

call.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        // any additional runnable items go in here
        try {


            String jsonData = response.body().string(); // the exception is caught at this point
            Log.d("<Mensajes>",jsonData);
            extractCreate = parseExtractCreateDetails(jsonData);
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                   extractCreate = parseExtractCreateDetails(jsonData);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("<=====>", "check");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Is this even working?");


                        }
                    });
                }
            //getStops(jsonData);

        }catch(IOException e) {

        }catch (JSONException e){

        }


    }
});
} // end of asyncCreate
```

What I am having trouble understanding is how the logs work but I get no information from the debugger. Is there a specific way to handle this sort of things inside `Fragments`? is it convention to handle them somewhere else like for example the activity calling the `Fragment`? and if so how would this be passed on to the `Fragment` activity?

Answer (score 0):

enqueue makes the request in background thread... It stops at the breakpoints inside response or failure after getting the response.It will take time and depends on internet and several things for the time it takes

Comment: Would you say that there are other conventions that are commonly followed for such cases? if handling the request in the ui thread is not recommended I would prefer to change that.

Comment: enqueue method itself runs on background thread.Thats why the break points after will get invoked.Breakpoints inside response or failure will be invoked when the response is received.